# Delayed system of differential equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, solver, differential-equations

I wrote the following DDE in Mathematica:

```
sol = NDSolve[{ x'[t]=0.2x[t]+1.4y[t]+0.5y[t-]-2,
                y'[t]=-0.2x[t]+0.4y[t]+2,
                x[t /; t <= 0] == 2, 
                y[t /; t <= 0] == 2},
                {x,y},{t,0,10} ]
```

But I'm getting those errors :

> Item 2 requested in Delayed time '1' = '2' computed at '3' = '4' did not evaluate to a real number. out of range; 1 items available.

> General::stop: Further output of StringForm::sfr will be suppressed during this calculation.

> NDSolve::rdelay: Delayed time –1. = '2' computed at '3' = '4' did not evaluate to a real number.

Could you please explain how I can fix these errors?

Comment: These changes appear to make it work `=1;NDSolve[{x'[t]==0.2x[t]+1.4y[t]+0.5y[t-]-2, y'[t]==-0.2x[t]+0.4y[t]+2,x[t/;t<=0]==2,y[t/;t<=0]==2},{x,y},{t,0,10}]`

Comment: @Bill Thank you, this helps a lot. You are right, I forgot to initialize .

Comment: and used `=` in two places where `==` was required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Bill in the comments, the following would fix the error.

```mathematica
=1;NDSolve[{x'[t]==0.2x[t]+1.4y[t]+0.5y[t-]-2,
y'[t]==-0.2x[t]+0.4y[t]+2,x[t/;t<=0]==2,y[t/;t<=0]==2},{x,y},{t,0,10}]
```

In my first version of the code,  was not initialized, and '=' instead of '==' were used.